# How to fetch object from redux store in parent route and make it available to child routes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm using React, Redux and React Router with nested routes. Say, I have the following route declaration and (container) components:

### Routes

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/parts">
        <Route path=":partId" component={Part}>
            <Route path="edit" component={EditPart}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

### Part

```
const Part = ({ part, children }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>{part.title}</h1>
        {children}
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => state.parts.find(part => part.id === props.params.partId)

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Part)
```

What's the best way to avoid repeating the steps taken in Part's `mapStateToProps()` function in the child component `EditPart` to get at the part object? Is there a way to pass the full object down from `Part` to `EditPart`?

Somebody suggested using `React.children` and `React.createElement()` in the parent component to override the props passed to its children, but I believe this isn't the cleanest approach.

Or do you think it's okay to refetch the object by its id (probably multiple times) in child routes? Maybe react-router's onEnter hook could help?

I feel I'm missing some key piece of the puzzle to handle this in a sensible way... Thanks for enlightening me! :)

Comment: Using `{React.cloneElement(children, { part })}` instead of just `{children}` in the `Edit` (parent) component does the job, but I'd like to know whether there are better approaches? Maybe solving this with nested routes is not the best solution in the first place?

Comment: I also had this problem and found the only solution with `React.cloneElement`. I think it's solid enough. Once react-router v4 is properly released, it will make more sense to move the routes around and not keep them into a single file, so passing props to child routes will be as natural as passing them to child components.